# How to fix additional period being added in french datetime?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Currently I am trying to figure out how I can format the month for french datetime to not include the ".".

i.e i want to change this:

```
    31 juill. 2018
```

to

```
    31 juill 2018
```

I'm trying to see if theres a better way than doing something like

```
    dateTime.replace(".", "");
```

Since I want to see if theres a way to manipulate the code so that the period doesnt show up in the first place?

you can see the code here demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/u0cL5pem/2/

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? When you shorten the name of a month in French, you have to denote it with the period.

Comment: @marekful it is just an ask we have from our client

Comment: What are your criteria for "better"? How is the string generated? You should post your code here, see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Probably a duplicate of [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date).

Comment: hi robg, agreed with the duplicate actually--i wanted to see if there were other, more elegant methods to format the date